# Sorting Js Array according to pre-defined array of indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

hope you can help me fix this.

So I have one array with nested arrays:

```
mainArr: [[Carl, 20, Male],[Mike, 30, Male], [Chloe, 45, Female], ...]
```

Now this array needs to be sorted along another array containing a set order of indexes from the array above.

```
indexArr: [2,1,3,...]
```

Result here being:

```
sortedArr: [[Mike, 30, Male], [Carl, 20, Male], [Chloe, 45, Female], ...]
```

I thought about writing a ForEach loop with the second array, something along the lines of:

```
indexArr.forEach(i){
 sortedArr.push(mainArr[indexArr[i]]);
};
```

But I'm trying to avoid using loops with this function to keep it fast. I couldn't find anything relevant to my problem in any array documentation. Do you know a way to fill sortedArr or sort mainArr efficiently?

Comment: Don't think there's anything faster than your forEach loop

Comment: You can't do this without iterating over the entries in the array (whether that's an explicit for/foreach loop or an implicit loop such as map).

Answer (score 4):

```
    indexArr.map(ind => mainArr[ind - 1])
```

Comment: Perfect, should've thought of that! Thanks alot

Comment: good answer using a loop, which is necessary

Comment: Each read with the array of positions, e.g. `const item = mainArr[sortArr[index]]` will have a constant number of steps (`O(1)` complexity). Still, you will need to go through the entire array for picking up all the items, an action whose number of steps increases as you have more items (`O(n)` complexity, which is what you're attempting to void).

In this sense, I see no way out of looping to obtain all the items you need, regardless of the array method you use (e.g., this `map` will not avoid looping through the items), with no complexity difference - `push` or this approach will be O(1).

Comment: I've realized you're right, there's no way escaping the loop in this. It'll have to do!